# How to Diagnose ElasticSearch Search Queue Growth

Tags: java, performance, elasticsearch, queue

I'm trying to diagnose an issue where our ElasticSearch search queue seemingly randomly fills up.

The behavior we observe in our monitor is that on one node of our cluster the search queue growth (just one) and after the search thread pool is used up we start getting timeouts of course. There seems to be one query that is blocking the while thing. The only way for us to resolve the problem at the moment is to restart the node.

You can see below the relevant behavior in charts: First the queue size, then the pending cluster tasks (to show that no other operations are blocking or queing up, e.g. index operations or so) and finally the active threads for the search thread pool. The spike at 11 o'clock is the restart of the node.

[image]

The log files on all nodes show no entries during an hour before or after the issue until we restarted the node. Only garbage collection events of around 200 -600ms and only one on the relevant node but that is around 20 minutes before the event.

My questions:
- how can I debug this as there is no information logged anywhere on a failing or timing out query?
- what are possible reasons for this? We don't have dynamic queries or anything similar
- can I set a query timeout or clear / reset active searches when this happens to prevent a node restart?

Some more details that don't apply, based on questions so far:

- exactly same hardware (16 cores, 60GB mem)
- same config, no special nodes
- no swap enabled
- nothing noticeable on other metrics like IO or CPU
- not a master node
- no special shards, three shards per node each node, pertty standard queries, all queries getting send to ES for 10 minutes before are queries that typically finish within 5-10ms, all the ones we get a timeout on are the same, no increase in query rate or anything else
- we have 5 nodes for this deployment, all accessed round robin
- we have a slow log of 2 seconds on info level, no entries

The hot threads after 1 minute of queue build up are at https://gist.github.com/elm-/5ed398054ea6b46522c0, several snapshots of some dumps over a few moments.

Comment: We opted for a 2.3 upgrade, it looks like it works so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Andrei Stefan's answer isn't wrong but I'd start by looking at the hot_threads from the clogged up node rather than trying to figure out what might be special about the node.

I don't know of a way for you to look inside the queue. Slowlogs, like Andrei says, are a great idea though.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense, will do it next time it happens, I did not know this existed as an API.

Comment: I posted some dumps, can't make too much of it though, doesn't look like too many are stuck on search. Most are networking waits. The gist is at https://gist.github.com/elm-/5ed398054ea6b46522c0 it contains the hot threads from all 5 nodes after the queue has been building for one minute, the node with the blocking queue is 03. There are several hot thread dumps over a small period to see change.

Comment: > org.apache.lucene.codecs.blocktree.FieldReader.ramBytesUsed(FieldReader.java:187)

Implies that you are using an old version. I think that particular hot item was fixed and upgrading should make that go away. But...

>        org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.IndexFieldDataService.getForField(IndexFieldDataService.java:264)

Implies the trouble is building field data. Field data is an "uninverted" data structure of your field, built in memory on the fly to make aggregations fast. You should switch new indexes to doc_values, which replaces field_data but is on disk. And probably upgrade.

Comment: Sorry for the malformed comment. SO doesn't make that easy.

Comment: Know your pain =) Thanks for the hints, could find some reports online on the same regard, I'm just going through the 1.7.* release notes right now to check if it was addressed and we will then do a rolling upgrade if it is there.  The doc_values was already on our TODO list, but current memory usage for it is at around 100MB per node, nothing too high from what we read, but worth testing as well.

Comment: I don't think it is the memory usage that is biting you - I think it is the generated on the fly part. I see lots of other threads waiting on the generation. Are you, perchance, loading a bunch of data in a large bulk or with a very high refresh interval?

Comment: We do large and high frequency indexing on the cluster, but in bursts and not at the same time as the queue build happens so far. Refresh interval is set to 30 seconds for high bursts, 1 second for real time afterwards. We index bursts of up to 500MB/s for 10-20 minutes, our constant indexing rate is at maybe 1 MB/s. The high bursts did not happen within or after 30 minutes of the queue issue so far, this was my first thought if there was a connection.

Comment: It happened again today on 1.7.5, stack trace show the getFieldData thread appearing quite often, we will try the doc_values next.

Comment: we can still reproduce the problem, we are now on 1.7.5 and all fields are doc_values where possible (actually have no measurable effect on performance, average query times stayed the same). The queue build up still happens, the hot threads are at https://gist.github.com/elm-/4d3dca3fd505428a8da5 and the growing node is the -03 node

Comment: Do you have any other ideas how to debug this further? I'm running out of ideas except to try ES 2 / report a bug for 1.7.5.

Answer (score 2):

That's a very open-ended investigation as there can be many things of fault. A rogue query can be the most obvious reason, but the question is why the other nodes are not affected. The most relevant clue in my opinion is, why is that node so special.

Things to look at:

- compare hardware specs between nodes
- compare configuration settings. See if this nodes stands out with something different.
- look at swapping on all nodes, if swapping is enabled. Check `mlockall` to see if it's set to `true`.
- in your monitoring tool correlate the queue size increasing with other things: memory usage, CPU usage, disk IOPS, GCs, indexing rate, searching rate
- is this node the master node when that queue fill up is happening?
- look at the shards distribution: is there any "special" shard(s) on this node that stands out? Correlate that with the queries you usually run. Maybe routing is in play here.
- are you sending the queries to the same node, or you do a round-robin query execution to all nodes
- try to enable slowlogs and decrease the threshold and try to catch that allegedly problematic query (if there is one)

Comment: I updated the questions with details on your questions, to sum up: Most don't apply =) or helped us so far

Comment: Ok. I needed to eliminate the obvious things first. As @Nik mentioned, hot_threads: `GET /_nodes/hot_threads?threads=1000` during the high CPU periods. And probably you'd want the output to put it in a file somewhere (gist, for example). Also, the output will contain the nodes' names, I see you obfuscated those in the printscreens, you might want to do the same with the hot_threads output.

Comment: Thanks, I will do it the next time we hit the queue issue. I actually created a load test using all the queries we send to the ES cluster and node at that time (we keep trace logs that log all this stuff), so I have the same load pattern. It's running since 30 minutes without any issues, so it looks more like a locking problem or something to me. We didn't hit ES harder than usual, averages at around 50 q/s with response times of 5-10ms each for the period of 40 minutes. 

Regarding node names: Yeah, just obfuscated them because they contain a customer name.

Comment: What ES version is this?

Comment: We use 1.6.2 at the moment.

Comment: It happened again, the hot thread dumps are at at https://gist.github.com/elm-/5ed398054ea6b46522c0 it contains the hot threads from all 5 nodes after the queue has been building for one minute, the node with the blocking queue is 03. There are several hot thread dumps over a small period to see change. I can't make too much of it, for me only the marvel export and the two threads with the search / field data look interesting but also not unexpected.

Comment: What I'm seeing is that only node `cpy-srv-somenode-elastic-03` is actually searching. Do you have shards from that index that's being searched only on that node? Are you sending the search requests only to that node? Why only one node is searching and others don't?

Comment: Also, how is memory and the old GCs during this time? Any memory pressure?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The others finished searching, only node3 is building up the search queue, all others are not affected / return results. It's not tied to a specific index, we are actually live indexes at least once a day and the indexes that were queried on today's locking issue are different ones then yesterday. Again, no old GC or memory issues that stand out. Last GC on the node was 5 minutes before, average duration of old GC is 600ms every 10-20 minutes per node.

Comment: Interesting. Are you using routing or `preference`? Do you have any custom plugins?

Comment: And I'd suggest upgrading to 1.7.5 and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Upgrading to 1.7.5 (see other comments stream), we are not using any custom plugins or using routing or preference settings for shards.

Comment: It happened again today on 1.7.5, stack trace show the getFieldData thread appearing quite often (see other answer comments), we will try the doc_values next to see if it is an issue that the threads are blocking on calculating the field data, as the other poster suggested..

Comment: Problem still persists also with 1.7.5 and doc values, hot threads are at gist.github.com/elm-/4d3dca3fd505428a8da5 and the growing node is the -03 node, do you have any other ideas to try and check, or is this a case for a bug report?

Comment: We had it now that it continuously happens every few minutes and we had to restart the whole cluster. Then it is fine again for a long period of time.

Comment: I also checked the hot threads outside of the queue issue, they look the same, spending lot of time in the field data, nothing too special I see as a difference there.